# How do i type file name and press enter for uploading file while using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, sendkeys

first week coding. I am creating a programme in python to automatically upload invoices into a job management system. I am using selenium to navigate through webpages and click upload. i am prompt with the upload file box and all i want to do is type the file name and press enter.

The upload file box opens and is ready for me to type how do i do this then carry on using selenium?

[image: code] 
[image: box]

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: I don't see what code is on image. Always put code as text.

Comment: did you try `sendkeys()`  (without `click()` before) or put text directly in `<input type="file">` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find `<input type="file">` and use `sendkeys("/path/filename")` without `click()` on this element. And later click button which sends it.

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/upload')

filename = '/full/path/to/file'

driver.find_element_by_id('file-upload').send_keys(filename)
driver.find_element_by_id('file-submit').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know selenium doesn't support windows based pop up handling so use Autoit tool to write a script with desired file name.

Inject same script in your selenium test function.